# Which library the program is linked to that provides a given function?

Tags: c, gdb

I have a program invoking function `foo` that is defined in a library. How can I know where the library is in the file system? (like is it a static library or a dynamically linked lib?)

Update: with using `ldd`, the program has a lot of dependency library. How to tell which lib contains function `foo`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know which library a specific function is defined in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563354/how-to-know-which-library-a-specific-function-is-defined-in) Voting to close that way because of upvote count ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't say which OS you are on, and the answer is system-dependent.

On Linux and most UNIX systems, you can simply ask the linker to tell you. For example, suppose you wanted to know where `printf` is coming from into this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  return printf("Hello\n");
}

$ gcc -c t.c
$ gcc t.o -Wl,-y,printf
t.o: reference to printf
/lib/libc.so.6: definition of printf
```

This tells you that `printf` is referenced in `t.o` and defined in `libc.so.6`. Above solution will work for both static and shared libraries.

Since you tagged this question with `gdb`, here is what you can do in gdb:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...done.

(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400528
(gdb) run

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400528 in main ()
(gdb) info symbol &printf
printf in section .text of /lib/libc.so.6
```

If `foo` comes from a shared library, `gdb` will tell you which one. If it comes from a static library (in which case `gdb` will say `in section .text of a.out`), use the `-Wl,-y,foo` solution above. You could also do a "brute force" solution like this:

```
find / -name '*.a' -print0 | xargs -0 nm -A | grep ' foo$'
```

Answer (score 5):

For shared libs try using `ldd` command line tool.

For static libs the library is **in** the program itself - there are no external dependencies, which is the whole point of using static libs.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot list static libraries in the final binary. To list the linked dynamic libraries, use the commands: On Linux, use `ldd [file]`. On Mac OS X, use `otool -L [file]`. On Windows, I have no idea ;-)