# How to know which library a specific function is defined in?

Tags: gdb, objdump

```
[root@xxx memcached-1.4.5]# objdump -R memcached-debug |grep freeaddrinfo
0000000000629e10 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  freeaddrinfo
```

...

```
(gdb) disas freeaddrinfo
Dump of assembler code for function freeaddrinfo:
0x00000037aa4baf10 <freeaddrinfo+0>:    push   %rbp
0x00000037aa4baf11 <freeaddrinfo+1>:    push   %rbx
0x00000037aa4baf12 <freeaddrinfo+2>:    mov    %rdi,%rbx
```

So I know `freeaddrinfo` is a dynamically linked function,but how to know which `.so` it's defined in?

Comment: You seriously need to review your questions and accept some answers.

Answer (score 8):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526511/which-library-the-program-is-linked-to/5533801#5533801). The `info symbol freeadrinfo` is one way to find out.

On Linux and Solaris you can also use `ldd` and `LD_DEBUG=symbols`. For example, if you wanted to find out where `localtime` in `/bin/date` is coming from:

```
LD_DEBUG=bindings ldd -r /bin/date 2>&1 |  grep localtime
     26322: binding file /bin/date [0] to /lib/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `localtime' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

Answer (score 2):

For certain low version gdb, "info symbol " could not work as you want.

So please use below method:

1. Run 'p symbol_name' to get symbol address

   `(gdb) p test_fun
   $1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x84bcc4 <test_fun>`
2. Check /proc/**PID**/maps to find out the module which the symbol address is in.

   `# more /proc/23275/maps 
   007ce000-0085f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 3524598    /usr/lib/libtest.so`

   0x84bcc4 is in [007ce000, 0085f000]

Answer (score 0):

Inside the libraries directory you could execute the following command to search for a specific symbol on all libraries:

```
for file in $(ls -1 *.so); do echo "-------> $file"; nm $file; done | c++filt | grep SYMBOL*
```

An enhanced version would be to list all libraries that are linked to the executable (through *ldd*) and go after each library listed searching if the symbol is defined there. Depending on your *nix you might have to tweak the *cut* parsing:

```
APP=firefox; for symbol in $(nm -D $APP | grep "U " | cut -b12-); do for library in $(ldd $APP | cut -d ' ' -f3- | cut -d' ' -f1); do for lib_symbol in $(nm -D $library | grep "T " | cut -b12-); do if [ $symbol == $lib_symbol ]; then echo "Found symbol: $symbol at [$library]"; fi ; done; done; done;
```

Comment: Your first version can be much reduced if you use 'nm -A'. And $(ls -1 *.so) is completely bogus -- *.so would have worked just as well.