# How to Determine Which Shared Library a Function Belongs to in gdb?

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries, callstack

When I get the callstack from gdb, I only get function names and source file information.

```
(gdb) f
#0  main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff1d4) at main.c:5
```

I don't get which Shared Library or Application the function belongs to.

On Windows, Windbg or Visual Studio will show callstacks with "myDll!myFunc" format, which shows you which module the function belongs to.

Currently in gdb I'm using "info address [function]" to get the address of the function symbol, and then use "info share" to manually find the range in which the function lies in memory to determine which library it is in.

Anyway to see the library directly without this manual process?

Comment: There is another method instead of info symbol.
[see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563354/how-to-know-which-library-a-specific-function-is-defined-in/40990769#40990769)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `info symbol`. It prints a library name for a function.

Like this:

```
(gdb) info symbol f
f(double) in section .text of libmylib_gcc.so

(gdb) info symbol printf
printf in section .text of /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Comment: I have found that I am unable to view virtual methods using this method.  If the symbol is a virtual function in a class gdb complains.

Comment: How to do that by address (i.e. look up lib of the current frame)?